# Get data from URL based on the data inside span

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get data from a URL and only retrieve the data from within the span that has title="" 
Each "row" of data has a span with a different incremental value of the title for example

```
title="1", title="2"
```

so the data I want to get will be inside this span
DATA HERE
x will be an incremental number

I am able to get all data from the page using this code however I am stuck on how to achieve what i need

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.example.com");
//parsing all content:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo "$html";
```

The data is formatted like :

```
<span id="RANDOMINFO">
 <a href="/DEMO/RANDOMDATA">+</a>
 <span title="1">DATA I WANT HERE</span> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/RANDOM">CLICK</a> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/RANDOM">RANDOM DATA</a>
</span>
<span id="RANDOMINFO">
 <a href="/DEMO/RANDOMDATA">+</a>
 <span title="2">DATA I WANT HERE</span> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/RANDOM">CLICK</a> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/RANDOM">RANDOM DATA</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Please add the response from the url. You should be able to get what you need using domdoc or xpath.

Comment: have added response

Comment: And here is the [DomDocument Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Yeah i saw that but am still totally puzzled and non the wiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution:***
Explanation is available as comments in the provided code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $element ) { //Loops through all available span elements
    if (empty($element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value) || $element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value != 'RANDOMINFO') { // Discards irrelevant span elements based on their `ID`. A similar sorting is achieved with `empty()` as the target `span` doesn't have any associated `ID`.
        echo get_inner_html($element).PHP_EOL; 
    }
}


function get_inner_html( $node ) {
    $innerHTML= '';
    $children = $node->childNodes;

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $child ); //fetches the text inside child elements of the targeted element
    }

    return $innerHTML;
}
```

***Output:***

```
DATA I WANT HERE
DATA I WANT HERE
```

***References:***

1. [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)
2. [DOMNamedNodeMap::getNamedItem](http://php.net/manual/en/domnamednodemap.getnameditem.php)
3. [DOMDocument::saveHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

Comment: Nothing is being returned at all now .. getting no data from the page

Comment: I tested this using your sample html, try modifying it based on the actual html, then let me know

Comment: checkout [my test code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c709efb730ee8a00fc88bad4d92f02c5ed685dc)

Comment: ok can see data again
ah sorry my mistake .. its the id value i need in the 1st span

Comment: you can get the `ID` value using `$element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value` where `$element` is an iteration `$doc->getElementsByTagName('span')`

Comment: Ive tried $mydata = element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value;
then echo $mydata.PHP_EOL 
however I'm getting the error yntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: your syntax is incorrect, use `$mydata = $element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value;` this should be done inside `foreach` loop

Comment: Sorry I had left work for the day will accept now ..
Can we continue in chat as I have another question related to this I'd like to ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181274/discussion-between-chris-yates-and-jaswinder-singh).